# How to handle missing data in KNN without imputing?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

I'm working on an assignment where I need to do KNN Regression using the sklearn library--but, if I have missing data (assume it's missing-at-random) I am not supposed to impute it. Instead, I have to leave it as null and somehow in my code account for it to ignore comparisons where one value is null.

For example, if my observations are (1, 2, 3, 4, null, 6) and (1, null, 3, 4, 5, 6) then I would ignore both the second and the fifth observations.

Is this possible with the sklearn library?

ETA: I would just drop the null values, but I won't know what the data looks like that they'll be testing and it could end up dropping anywhere between 0% and 99% of the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends a little on what exactly you're trying to do.

1. **Ignore all columns with nulls**: I imagine this isn't what you're asking since that's more of a data pre-processing step and isn't really unique to sklearn. Even in pure python, just search for column indices containing nulls and construct a new data set with those indices filtered out.
2. **Ignore null values in vector comparisons**: This one is actually kind of fun. Essentially you're saying something like the distance between `[1, 2, 3, 4, None, 6]` and `[1, None, 3, 4, 5, 6]` is `sqrt(1*1 + 3*3 + 4*4 + 6*6)`. In this case you need some kind of a custom metric, which sklearn supports. Unfortunately you can't input null values into the KNN `fit()` method, so even with a custom metric you can't quite get what you want. The solution is to pre-compute distances. E.g.:

```
from math import sqrt, isfinite

X_train = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, None, 6],
    [1, None, 3, 4, 5, 6],
]
y_train = [3.14, 2.72]  # we're regressing something

def euclidean(p, q):
  # Could also use numpy routines
  return sqrt(sum((x-y)**2 for x,y in zip(p,q)))

def is_num(x):
  # The `is not None` check needs to happen first because of short-circuiting
  return x is not None and isfinite(x)

def restricted_points(p, q):
  # Returns copies of `p` and `q` except at coordinates where either vector
  # is None, inf, or nan
  return tuple(zip(*[(x,y) for x,y in zip(p,q) if all(map(is_num, (x,y)))]))

def dist(p, q):
  # Note that in this form you can use any metric you like on the
  # restricted vectors, not just the euclidean metric
  return euclidean(*restricted_points(p, q))

dists = [[dist(p,q) for p in X_train] for q in X_train]
knn = KNeighborsRegressor(
    n_neighbors=1,  # only needed in our test example since we have so few data points
    metric='precomputed'
)
knn.fit(dists, y_train)

X_test = [
    [1, 2, 3, None, None, 6],
]
# We tell sklearn which points in the knn graph to use by telling it how far
# our queries are from every input. This is super inefficient.
predictions = knn.predict([[dist(q, p) for p in X_train] for q in X_test])
```

There's still an open question of what to do if you have nulls in the outputs you're regressing to, but your problem statement doesn't make it sound like that's an issue for you.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for! Just to clarify, data is X_train, outputs is y_train, and query_data is X_test?

Comment: Thank you, but I'm getting an error on knn.fit: `ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').` I pasted everything in exactly, and added my code to the original question.

Comment: I bungled up the distance equation. You were probably taking the square root of negative values. One sec.

Comment: Wonderful work, thank you. However, since there are still null values in dist it throws an error when fitting. Have I just missed a step?

Comment: Not necessarily. That depends on how you're loading your data in. In the `dist(p, q)` function I have defined above it assumes that the only element value we want to exclude is `None`. If you're using pandas or numpy or a few other things to, e.g., read data from a csv then you might have NaN values or something similar that are still causing problems.

Comment: Check if the updated nan handling suffices for your data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197959/discussion-between-carousallie-and-hans-musgrave).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("your_data.csv")

df.dropna(inplace = True)
```

Comment: Thank you! The only issue with this is I don't know what the data will look like when they test my code after submission, so it could be 40% of the data missing. Is there any other way around this?

Comment: Indeed, If you drop null values you can loose valuable data. Maybe it would be better to replace it with mean or median value